# Default input CSS changes in different browsers. Why?

Tags: css, forms, browser, input

I have a created a few forms and I can't fgure out why in certain browsers and operating systems, my input buttons appear differently.

Check out the input button here:  http://www.41q.org/admin

It's should appear as a square, but instead I get a round corder default button.  Can;t figure this out.  My CSS is not working.

Should I change the TYPE?

Erik

Comment: Which browsers and operating systems? Chrome on XP gives a square-corner button.

Comment: So do Firefox and IE9 on Win7.

Comment: square-corner button on Chrome/ubuntu. your may need an addition 'border: 0 !important;' rule for '.login2';

Comment: Its weird because if you go to www.41q.org , my GO button appeas correctly.  There's no pattern or reason?

Comment: Go button is square at 41q.org as well. I also see no CSS anywhere related to round corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using normalize.css (http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) or reset.css (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Then optimize for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an IE problem.

I like to define the body font family or font styles with the input, option, textarea, etc tags, like this:

```
body, input, select, option, textarea {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial;
}
```